# Error "undefined reference" while linking in MinGW

Tags: linker, mingw

I have got the `object-file` from source code using `MinGW`.

But on linking:

```
ld -o test.exe test.o
```

I get errors, for example the following:

> undefined reference to printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can view commands ran by compiler via command

```
c99 -v test.o
```

We'll get some text. All after string which contains "COLLECT_CGG_OPTIONS" will be arguments of ld.
But size of executable file is much more then size of file got by previous way.

Answer (score 2):

First, why are you using ld directly?

The following is an excerpt from the "GCC and Make" tutorial found at http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html.

Compile and Link Separately

The above command compile the source file into object file and link with other object files (system library) into executable in one step. You may separate compile and link in two steps as follows:

```
// Compile-only with -c option
> g++ -c -Wall -g Hello.cpp
// Link object file(s) into an executable
> g++ -g -o Hello.exe Hello.o
```

Note g++ (you can substitute gcc if you are using C and not C++) is used both for compiling and linking. ld is not used at all.

The benefit of using g++ or gcc to link is that it will link with default libraries, such as the one you need to link with for printf, automatically.

To link with other libraries, you specify the library name with the -l parameter, as in -lmylib.

Comment: My teacher wants I do it with ld.
I red about -l key, but I don't know which library contains printf.

Comment: I tried it and got following:
     `'undefined reference to '__main'`
Then I added -lgcc (before -lmsvsrt) and got following:
     `undefined reference to '_pei386_runtime_relocator'`
How I can understand what must be included generally?

Comment: I do not know. This is why it is best to use gcc or g++ for linking and not ld. I did a Google search and I did not find a solution to this problem. In fact, every resource I found said link with gcc or g++.

Comment: You're probably long out of university by now, but your professor wanted you to use a real Unix (Linux) environment, and the answer is `-lc`. The library is `c` as in the C Library. Lives in /lib/libc.so.6 or /usr/lib/libc.a