# Header inclue issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, header

I'd like to test a new IDE to code in C++, so I started using Visual Studio Code. So far, I had used CodeBlocks and QtEditor, which are easier for me because the compiler is already installed.

I struggled with how to Run and Debug a code with MinGW (I'm on Windows), and now I cannot achieve to include functions' header files. Indeed, with CodeBlocks, I made a `.cpp` file for my functions and I included it in my main file with a header with the `extern` specifier and it worked perfectly.
I did the same thing in Visual Studio Code, however I have this error:

```
undefined reference to `my function'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my header, I wrote:

```cpp
#ifndef GENERATETONE_HPP
#define GENERATETONE_HPP

#include <cmath>

extern void generateData(double freq, double amount_time);

#endif // GENERATETONE_HPP
```

And of course I wrote `#include "generatetone.hpp"` in my main function and in `generatetone.cpp`.

The thing that bothers me is the fact that when I declare all my functions in the header with the `inline` specifier (that is to say that I delete the `.cpp` file), it works.

I also want to say that I wrote exactly the same thing in CodeBlocks and it works, therefore I'm totally confused.

I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Your problem is you have not specified that  generatetone.cpp must be compiled and linked. Unfortunately I'm not a user of VSC and do not know which configuration file you need to edit in order to make the file compile and link.

Comment: With VS Code, it becomes easier to just use a build system once you need multiple files compiled. There are ways to tweak your build task, but I don't recommend it because it always re-compiles everything. With the cmake extension, you still get one-buttom compiles, and you don't need to know a whole lot about cmake for smaller multi-file projects.

Comment: cmake is another compiler that i have to install isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your complier doesn't find your root dictionary about where the exact header resources are.
Hoping following links might help u.
[Error "undefined reference" while linking in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483173/error-undefined-reference-while-linking-in-mingw)
[Error "undefined reference" while linking in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483173/error-undefined-reference-while-linking-in-mingw)